# Symfony file permission issues

Tags: linux, apache, symfony, file-permissions, symfony-cache

I have a Symfony 4 project on Fedora 28 (a Linux Distribution), Apache 2.4.33 and PHP 7.2.5. All of that is hosted on a VPS (Virtual Private Server). And it's the first time that I deploy a Symfony project online (I was using before that the Symfony built-in PHP Server that is not recommended for Production uses).

And I was ready to use my Symfony Project, I cleared my cache and went to `localhost/MyProject/public/index.php/` (Note: I didn't go exactly here, my project is online, I used another URL, but, that doesn't change anything). When I seen [this beautiful exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJeOv.png):

```
Unable to create the storage directory (/var/www/html/HAY/var/cache/dev/profiler).
```

What a beautiful and incomprehensible exception! Why? Because my `/var/www/html` his owner is apache:apache (Note: I also added apache in the root group and root in the apache group) and his file permission are all set to 777. Then, you'll say, why not just creating the `/var/www/html/HAY/var/cache/dev/profiler` directory? Because, when I make that... First of all, my profiler debug tool bar just DON'T work, and I have, this time, [another file permission exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxg2m.png):

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Failed to create "/var/www/html/HAY/var/cache/dev/translations"").
```

And why not creating `/var/www/html/HAY/var/cache/dev/translations`? I did it, and I have [this other exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUhZx.png). That I can't resolve... Why? Because of this:

```
total 16
drwxrwxrwx+ 2 apache apache 4096 May 20 14:00 .
drwxrwxrwx+ 8 apache apache 4096 May 20 14:00 ..
```

... WHY??? JUST WHY??? And that's a preview of what I did to try to resolve this insane issue!

```
  304  php bin/console cache:clear
  305  php bin/console cache:clear --env=PROD
  306  chown -R apache:apache ./
  307  ls -la
  308  chown -R root:root ./
  309  ls -al var/cache/dev/
  310  mkdir profiler
  311  rm profiler/
  312  rm -rf profiler/
  313  mkdir var/cache/dev/profiler
  314  cp templates/home.html.twig ../
  315  ls ..
  316  rm -rf ./
  317  cd ..
  318  rm -rf HAY/
  319  git clone https://github.com/TheOpenMedium/HAY.git
  320  cd HAY/
  321  composer install
  322  mv ../home.html.twig templates/home.html.twig 
  323  mv ../home.html.twig templates/home.html.twig 
  324  cat templates/home.html.twig 
  325  nano .env
  326  cat .env
  327  composer require apache-pack
  328  nano .env
  329  chmod -R 777 -R
  330  chmod -R 777 ./
  331  chmod -R 777 ./ -v
  332  chmod -R 777 var/cache/dev/ -v
  333  chmod -R 777 var/cache/dev/ -1v
  334  chmod -R 777 var/cache/dev/
  335  ls -la var/cache/dev/
  336  chmod -R 775 var/cache/dev/
  337  chmod -R 777 var/cache/dev/
  338  ls -al /var/www/
  339  find httpd.conf
  340  find / httpd.conf
  341  find --help
  342  find -D search / "httpd.conf"
  343  find --help
  344  history
  345  history | grep "httpd.conf"
  346  nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf 
  347  systemctl restart httpd.serice
  348  systemctl restart httpd.service
  349  systemctl status httpd.service
  350  nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf 
  351  systemctl status httpd.service
  352  systemctl restart httpd.service
  353  chown -R /var/www/html/ apache:apache
  354  chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/
  355  ls -al
  356  less public/index.php 
  357  cat public/index.php | grep "umask"
  358  chmod -R 777 var/log/
  359  nano .env
  360  php bin/console cache:warmup
  361  php bin/console cache:warmup
  362  nano .env
  363  php bin/console cache:warmup
  364  nano .env
  365  nano .env
  366  php bin/console cache:clear
  367  php bin/console cache:warmup
  368  nano .env
  369  php bin/console cache:clear
  370  php bin/console cache:warmup
  371  nano .env
  372  php bin/console cache:clear
  373  php bin/console cache:warmup
  374  mkdir var/cache/dev/profiler
  375  nano .env
  413  chmod -R 777 ./
  414  ls -la var/cache/dev/doctrine/orm/Proxies/
  415  ls -la var/cache/dev/doctrine/orm/
  416  chown -R apache:apache ./
  417  ls -la
  418  chown -R www-data:www-data ./
  419  users
  420  users --help
  421  usermod --help
  422  php bin/console cache:clear
  423  chmod -R 777 ./
  424  nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf 
  425  rm -rf var/cache/*
  426  rm -rf var/log/*
  427  chmod 777 var/cache
  428  chmod 777 var/log
  429  chmod -R 777 ./
  430  php bin/console doctrine:database:create
  431  php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
  432  ls -la var/cache
  433  ls -la var/cache/dev/
  434  chmod -R 777 ./
  435  sudo setfacl -R -m u:apache:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX var/cache/
  436  sudo setfacl -R -m u:apache:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX var/cache
  437  sudo setfacl -dR -m u:apache:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX var/cache var/log
  438  sudo setfacl -R -m u:apache:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX var/cache var/log
  439  sudo -u apache php bin/console cache:clear
  440  chmod -R 777 ./
```

Fun fact: before running `439  sudo -u apache php bin/console cache:clear` I had an exception... while handling an exception XD! #Inception!

Also, that's my httpd.conf:

```
#
# This is the main Apache HTTP server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/> for detailed information.
# In particular, see 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directives.html>
# for a discussion of each configuration directive.
#
# Do NOT simply read the instructions in here without understanding
# what they do.  They're here only as hints or reminders.  If you are unsure
# consult the online docs. You have been warned.  
#
# Configuration and logfile names: If the filenames you specify for many
# of the server's control files begin with "/" (or "drive:/" for Win32), the
# server will use that explicit path.  If the filenames do *not* begin
# with "/", the value of ServerRoot is prepended -- so 'log/access_log'
# with ServerRoot set to '/www' will be interpreted by the
# server as '/www/log/access_log', where as '/log/access_log' will be
# interpreted as '/log/access_log'.

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# Do not add a slash at the end of the directory path.  If you point
# ServerRoot at a non-local disk, be sure to specify a local disk on the
# Mutex directive, if file-based mutexes are used.  If you wish to share the
# same ServerRoot for multiple httpd daemons, you will need to change at
# least PidFile.
#
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"

#
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80

#
# Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
#
# To be able to use the functionality of a module which was built as a DSO you
# have to place corresponding `LoadModule' lines at this location so the
# directives contained in it are actually available _before_ they are used.
# Statically compiled modules (those listed by `httpd -l') do not need
# to be loaded here.
#
# Example:
# LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
#
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User apache
Group apache

# 'Main' server configuration
#
# The directives in this section set up the values used by the 'main'
# server, which responds to any requests that aren't handled by a
# <VirtualHost> definition.  These values also provide defaults for
# any <VirtualHost> containers you may define later in the file.
#
# All of these directives may appear inside <VirtualHost> containers,
# in which case these default settings will be overridden for the
# virtual host being defined.
#

#
# ServerAdmin: Your address, where problems with the server should be
# e-mailed.  This address appears on some server-generated pages, such
# as error documents.  e.g. admin@your-domain.com
#
ServerAdmin root@localhost

#
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
#ServerName www.example.com:80

#
# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other 
# <Directory> blocks below.
#
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

#
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
# you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
# below.
#

#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

#
# Relax access to content within /var/www.
#
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Further relax access to the default document root:
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride None

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
# viewed by Web clients. 
#
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

#
# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog "logs/error_log"

#
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    #
    # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
    # a CustomLog directive (see below).
    #
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    #
    # The location and format of the access logfile (Common Logfile Format).
    # If you do not define any access logfiles within a <VirtualHost>
    # container, they will be logged here.  Contrariwise, if you *do*
    # define per-<VirtualHost> access logfiles, transactions will be
    # logged therein and *not* in this file.
    #
    #CustomLog "logs/access_log" common

    #
    # If you prefer a logfile with access, agent, and referer information
    # (Combined Logfile Format) you can use the following directive.
    #
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    #
    # Redirect: Allows you to tell clients about documents that used to 
    # exist in your server's namespace, but do not anymore. The client 
    # will make a new request for the document at its new location.
    # Example:
    # Redirect permanent /foo http://www.example.com/bar

    #
    # Alias: Maps web paths into filesystem paths and is used to
    # access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot.
    # Example:
    # Alias /webpath /full/filesystem/path
    #
    # If you include a trailing / on /webpath then the server will
    # require it to be present in the URL.  You will also likely
    # need to provide a <Directory> section to allow access to
    # the filesystem path.

    #
    # ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts. 
    # ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
    # documents in the target directory are treated as applications and
    # run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the
    # client.  The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias
    # directives as to Alias.
    #
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

#
# "/var/www/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
# CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
#
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    #
    # TypesConfig points to the file containing the list of mappings from
    # filename extension to MIME-type.
    #
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types

    #
    # AddType allows you to add to or override the MIME configuration
    # file specified in TypesConfig for specific file types.
    #
    #AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
    #
    # AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
    # information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
    #
    #AddEncoding x-compress .Z
    #AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
    #
    # If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
    # probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
    #
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

    #
    # AddHandler allows you to map certain file extensions to "handlers":
    # actions unrelated to filetype. These can be either built into the server
    # or added with the Action directive (see below)
    #
    # To use CGI scripts outside of ScriptAliased directories:
    # (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    #AddHandler cgi-script .cgi

    # For type maps (negotiated resources):
    #AddHandler type-map var

    #
    # Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client.
    #
    # To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI):
    # (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

#
# Specify a default charset for all content served; this enables
# interpretation of all content as UTF-8 by default.  To use the 
# default browser choice (ISO-8859-1), or to allow the META tags
# in HTML content to override this choice, comment out this
# directive:
#
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    #
    # The mod_mime_magic module allows the server to use various hints from the
    # contents of the file itself to determine its type.  The MIMEMagicFile
    # directive tells the module where the hint definitions are located.
    #
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

#
# Customizable error responses come in three flavors:
# 1) plain text 2) local redirects 3) external redirects
#
# Some examples:
#ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
#ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
#ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
#ErrorDocument 402 http://www.example.com/subscription_info.html
#

#
# EnableMMAP and EnableSendfile: On systems that support it, 
# memory-mapping or the sendfile syscall may be used to deliver
# files.  This usually improves server performance, but must
# be turned off when serving from networked-mounted 
# filesystems or if support for these functions is otherwise
# broken on your system.
# Defaults if commented: EnableMMAP On, EnableSendfile Off
#
#EnableMMAP off
EnableSendfile on

# Supplemental configuration
#
# Load config files in the "/etc/httpd/conf.d" directory, if any.
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

And that is a `ls -la /var/www/html/HAY/`:

```
total 264
drwxrwxrwx. 12 apache apache   4096 May 19 22:22 .
drwxr-xr-x.  3 apache apache   4096 May 19 22:23 ..
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache apache   1000 May 19 23:10 .env
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache apache    923 May 19 22:22 .env.dist
drwxrwxrwx.  8 apache apache   4096 May 19 22:22 .git
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache apache    385 May 19 22:22 .gitignore
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache apache   3256 May 19 22:22 CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache apache    956 May 19 22:22 CONTRIBUTING.md
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache apache   2239 May 19 22:22 ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache apache   1067 May 19 22:22 LICENSE
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache apache   3483 May 19 22:22 README.md
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache apache   3982 May 19 22:22 READMEFR.md
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache apache     26 May 19 22:22 _config.yml
drwxrwxrwx.  2 apache apache   4096 May 19 22:22 bin
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache apache   2050 May 20 12:32 composer.json
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache apache 161543 May 20 12:29 composer.lock
drwxrwxrwx.  4 apache apache   4096 May 19 22:22 config
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache apache   1201 May 19 22:22 phpunit.xml.dist
drwxrwxrwx.  6 apache apache   4096 May 20 12:25 public
drwxrwxrwx.  6 apache apache   4096 May 19 22:22 src
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache apache   7910 May 20 12:29 symfony.lock
drwxrwxrwx.  7 apache apache   4096 May 19 22:23 templates
drwxrwxrwx.  3 apache apache   4096 May 19 22:22 tests
drwxrwxrwx.  2 apache apache   4096 May 19 22:22 translations
drwxrwxrwx.  4 apache apache   4096 May 19 22:22 var
drwxrwxrwx. 13 apache apache   4096 May 20 12:29 vendor
```

Thank you for taking the time of reading my question ;)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't exactly found a solution to my problem, but I resolved it.

I just reinstalled my VPS changing this time my OS from Fedora Cloud 28 to Ubuntu Server 18.04. I installed my website, and, I don't know why, it just worked... Maybe I made an error while configuring my VPS the first time or maybe, it's because I was running under Fedora Cloud (And not Fedora Server, but my VPS provider don't let me the choice.).

Then, if you have the same problem, just reinstall your VPS, maybe it will work...

Answer (score -1):

The user executing the web server and the user executing PHP page may not be the same. In fact, it is often purposefully changed by using one of several possible means (`suPHP`, `php-fpm` with `mod_proxy,`fcgi`).

From the error messages (which are quite clear IMHO) it definitely looks like you have in fact a different user running PHP. If you cannot find it in your configuration, I would suggest to access PHP info from the Symfony profiler toolbar and look for the `$_SERVER['USER']` variable.

Or, if everything else fail, temporarily add a couple of lines at the beginning of your `app_dev.php` so that it only outputs it:

```
die($_SERVER['user']);
```

and then execute it.

Hope this guide you at least into the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But what I discovered is that the `$_SERVER['USER']` is `"root"`... What does this mean?

Comment: That somehow your PHP is executed as `root` user. Of course this is strongly discouraged, but also it makes your issue weird, becase `root` should not have any permission issue. You should really check your server PHP configuration (or have it checked by your sysadmin / hosting provider)

Comment: Wow... That's weirder, according to my [phpinfo()](http://stable.hay.theopenmedium.org/phpinfo/), the `$_SERVER['USER']` is actually `apache`. NOTE: It's the Symfony Profiler that indicate that the user is root.

Comment: Is it possible to get a comment to understand why my answer was downvoted?

Comment: Not me, I don't have enough reputation, my question too has been downvoted and I don't know why...